# Rotating a set of 2D points about another point

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to rotate an array of coordinates about a given point. To realise that I rotate every coordinate by using a `for` loop and put the rotated coordinates back into my array. When executing the code I get `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1` so there must be a mistake inside the loop which I cannot identify.

```
import math
import numpy as np

airfoil = np.array([[3349.67075, 2138.     ],
       [3225.86375, 2137.77425],
       [3060.79325, 2137.757  ],
       [2901.63575, 2136.89675],
       [2803.16825, 2136.89   ],
       [2728.33625, 2136.719  ],
       [2687.33225, 2136.89   ],
       [2611.475  , 2136.377  ],
       [2600.     , 2138.     ],
       [2602.24925, 2146.457  ],
       [2605.66625, 2152.2665 ],
       [2611.475  , 2158.7585 ],
       [2618.65025, 2164.39625],
       [2638.12775, 2176.0145 ],
       [2680.49825, 2193.95375],
       [2725.0895 , 2208.134  ],
       [2786.08325, 2220.2645 ],
       [2853.398  , 2227.61075]])


theta = 1.5708  # 90 degree
ox, oy = 2000, 2000  # point to rotate about

for i in range(airfoil.shape[0]-1):
    qx = ox + math.cos(theta) * (airfoil[i][0] - ox) - math.sin(theta) * 
        (airfoil[i][1] - oy)
    qy = oy + math.sin(theta) * (airfoil[i][0] - ox) + math.cos(theta) * 
        (airfoil[i][1] - oy)
    airfoil = np.column_stack((qx, qy))
```

The elements (x and y coordinates) are callable with `airfoil[0][0]` or `airfoil[0][1]` to `airfoil[17][0]` and `airfoil[17][1]` without any problems. So the mistake must be somewhere else.

I already read similiar questions which could not help me.

Comment: You are overwriting the variable `airfoil` before you have finished iterating through it.

Comment: You ought to look up a bit of [linear algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093314/rotation-matrix-of-rotation-around-a-point-other-than-the-origin)  - construct an appropriate 2 by 2 matrix and multiply your data with this and it will perform all the rotational maths you want in a single step.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog so you suggest to take the last line out of the loop, store `qx` and `qy` in a separate array and stack them together afterwards?

Comment: Whatever you do, you should never overwrite something while you iterate over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have `airfoil = np.column_stack((qx, qy))` inside the loop is not a good idea since it modifies the `airfoil` array at every iteration. Actually, by doing `numpy.column_stack` you make airfoil have shape `(1,2)` after the first iteration overriding the original `airfoil` which has shape `(18,2)` (hence on the second iteration it gives you the shape error).

You would be better by storing the rotated points on another variable. And even better, perform the rotation all at once with a simple `A v = w`, where `A` is your rotation matrix, `v` your airfoil coordinates and `w` the rotated coordinates.

Here is what you could do using the rotation matrix `A`

```
theta = 1.5708  # 90 degree
ox, oy = 2000, 2000  # point to rotate about
A = np.matrix([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)],
               [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]])

w = np.zeros(airfoil.shape)
airfoil_shifted = airfoil-np.array([ox,oy])
for i,v in enumerate(airfoil_shifted):
  w[i] = A @ v
```

where `w` will contain the rotated coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code and it works now.

```
theta = 1.5708
ox, oy = 2000, 2000

qx = []
qy = []

for i in range(airfoil.shape[0]):
    qx.append(ox + math.cos(theta) * (airfoil[i][0] - ox) - math.sin(theta) * (airfoil[i][1] - oy))
    qy.append(oy + math.sin(theta) * (airfoil[i][0] - ox) + math.cos(theta) * (airfoil[i][1] - oy))

airfoil = np.column_stack((qx, qy))
```

Nevertheless I agree that using matrix multiplication is more elegant than my solution. Thanks!